# iOS - Where to initialize views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I want to initialize views programmatically, where in the viewcontroller lifecycle should this happen?

The initial intuition is **loadView**. However, here, we don't yet have the frame of the view itself (necessary for calculating the sizes/positions of the views). Ditto for **viewDidLoad**.

Next intuition is **viewWillAppear**- here we DO (finally) have a guarantee of the frame of the view. However, this has potential to be called many times throughout the vc lifecycle. Ditto for **viewDidAppear**, etc...

Finally, I found **viewWillLayoutSubviews**. This works for the initialization of most static layouts- however, whenever any view moves this gets called again (same problem as **viewWillAppear**).

I've seen recommendations to init the views in **loadView** and set their frames in **viewWillLayoutSubviews** (since setting frames should be idempotent, who cares if it gets called a couple times). But then why does apple so strongly encourage *initWithFrame:* as the standard initialization method of UIViews (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html)?

Would it be crazy to subclass all my UIViewControllers to have an *initWithViewFrame:* method? That way I can pass in a frame, manually set it immediately in **loadView** and be done with it? Or is it better to have a **viewHasBeenFormatted** flag in **viewWillAppear** that, if not set, calls the formatting of views and then sets it?

Or is this just apple's way of saying "use interface builder or you're screwed"?

Any help is appreciated!

***edit***- accidentally wrote loadView where I meant viewWillAppear (in final paragraph)

***update***-  I guess I've come to terms with the fact that there is no place where

1. The frame is confidently known
2. The code will only be run once (on setup)

Looks like you're expected to *initWithFrame:* all your views in **viewDidLoad** (but then I guess the contents of that view shouldn't treat that frame as even remotely final? because how could it be when it was derived on an assumption? ugh...). Then re-set their frames in **layoutSubviews**. And make sure to manually handle the differences between initial layout and layout as a result of a moved view there... Man I feel like I've GOT to be missing something... (lol denial...)

I guess that, OR submit and use IB.

***update2***- viewWillLayoutSubviews WILL get called when one of its subviews is resized. So it is still disqualified as it fails property 2 of the required characteristics that I'm looking for. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing layout with IB, it's fine to do additional view initialization in `viewDidLoad` (for example, if you need to do stuff that IB doesn't handle well, or if you have `UIView` subclasses with properties not supported by IB).  Alternatively, if you're not using IB, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) says you should use `loadView` to manually initialize your view hierarchy.

You're right, though, that you can't rely on the frame being accurate at that point.  So you can accomplish layout via each view's `autoResizingMask` property, layout constraints (if you're iOS 6 and later), and/or overriding `layoutSubviews`.

My usual approach is to do layout to some degree in IB, then do anything else I need to (nontrivial layout, custom classes, etc) in `viewDidLoad`.  Then, if I have layout to figure out that `autoResizingMask` doesn't cover (I'm supporting down to iOS 5), I override `viewWillAppear` (or `layoutSubviews` if I'm subclassing `UIView`) and do some pixel math.  I've got a category on `UIView` to help with this that has things like:

```
-(void)centerSubviewHorizontally:(UIView *)view pixelsFromTop:(float)pixels;
-(void)centerSubviewHorizontally:(UIView *)view pixelsBelow:(float)pixels siblingView:(UIView *)sibling;
```

Comment: Yep, I'm not using IB. I'm fine with initializing the hierarchy (who is subview of whom) in loadView. The issue comes from most initialization requiring (/encouraging) "initWithFrame", which I shouldn't be considering before I know the size/shape of the parent view. autoResizingMasks aren't sufficient for the layout I need (one reason for not using IB).

So basically, what I'm hearing is that there is **not** a place that is guaranteed to only be called once during a vc's lifecycle that also has access to the final frame of the view. Shucks. Makes me sad. :(

Comment: Also- one thing to note for future readers: `layoutSubviews` is a method on UIView, not UIViewController. So to override that would be to use a custom view. (Or use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, which IS on the viewController)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about doing layout more than once.  My approach is to do my initialization in a .xib as much as possible and cover everything else in `viewDidLoad`.  See my update for details.

Answer (score 2):

View controllers should **not** have `initWithFrame:` methods. What I do in all of my code (I never use IB) is to let the default `loadView` do its own thing. I create and setup all subviews in `viewDidLoad`. At this point the view controller's frame has at least a sane value. All subviews can be created with their own sane frames based on the initial size of the view controller's view. With proper `autoresizingMask` values this may be all you need.

If you need more specific subview layout, put the appropriate layout code in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method. This will deal with any view controller view frame changes including rotation, in-call status bars, etc.

Comment: You haven't switched to autolayout?

Comment: Isn't autolayout a function of IB? Then no. I've never used it. I do everything in code. IB makes no sense to me. I've been coding iOS apps for over 5 years and I have never felt the need for IB.

Comment: You can use autolayout without IB. Saves a lot of calculations.

Comment: Do you mean constraints?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know autolayout refers to the mechanism of calculating frames from constraints. IB is just a UI for it.

Comment: In my experience, it doesn't necessarily have a sane value... :/ If you're using tabvc/navvc/other weird stuff, it often comes out too short/too long (especially with this ios7 transition... yuck). As stated in one of my comments above, autoresizingmask isn't sufficient for me. And the reason I hesitate to use viewWillLayoutSubviews is because the second a view moves, that gets called again. I would really like a place to just set the initial framing of all my views, and handle when that needs to change somewhere else. Oh well. :(

Comment: @Phildo By "sane", I meant non-zero. Initially the view will be size of the screen. That has always worked for me. When it doesn't, using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` always works. And for the record, updating a subview's frame will not, in any way, result in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` being called again. All of my apps use this model and they all work.

Comment: @lassej Most of my apps still have iOS 5 support so no constraints. My main app that now supports iOS 6 and 7 has not been updated for constraints because all of the existing code already works. I will slowly migrate to constraints as needed.

Comment: @maddy - "updating a subview's frame will not, in any way, result in viewWillLayoutSubviews being called again" Wait- really?! If this is the case, then you've solved all my problems and I will accept yours as the correct answer! One sec, lemme try!

Comment: @Phildo Did you intend to add something to that quote?

Comment: @maddy ok. so I have a view with a tapgesturerecognizer. when it receives that tap, it resizes itself (animated). this DOES cause `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to be called again (in the viewcontroller whose view has this animating view as its subview). Am I doing something incorrectly to cause this?

Comment: @Phildo In my experience, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is only called when the frame of the view controller's view is changed. Are you doing this anywhere?

Comment: @maddy darn. after substantial testing (including ripping out all potentially distracting functionality), I have it reduced to a viewcontroller that: implements viewWillLayoutSubviews, its view contains a subview that has a tapgesturerecognizer, the tgr simply resizes the SUBview, and viewWillLayoutSubviews gets called every time the subview's frame is changed. :(

Comment: @Phildo Well what do you know. I never noticed this before. I just made a quick test app. It does appear that changing the frame of a direct subview of the view controller's view does result in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` being called. Changing further nested subviews does **not** result in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` being called. And changing a direct subview inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews` does not result in another call. This is good to know.

Comment: @maddy yeah, it's pretty ridiculous. I wonder if this is a bug? This behavior isn't mentioned anywhere (that I could find) in the docs... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: @Phildo After some though it actually makes perfect sense. The whole idea of the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is so the subviews of a view controller can get positioned properly. If one direct subview of the view controller's view is changed, you may need to adjust the layout of the other subviews. But ideally it would be nice if there was one thing when the view controller's view changes and another for when a subview changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use interface builder you should override loadView and initialize the views there. If you use autolayout you can also add your constraints there. If you don't use autolayout you can override the layoutSubviews method of your views to adjust the frames.

Comment: according to the docs, the proper place to add constraints is updateViewConstraints

Comment: I think updateViewConstraints should be used for changing the constraints, not for initialization. If you use interface builder the constraints are added during loadView.

Comment: ref docs state "You may override this method in a subclass in order to add constraints to the view or its subviews"